# How should two .NET components to communicate over a LAN?

Tags: .net, network-protocols

I'm writing my first client-server app with .NET and there are many possible protocols and libraries I could use: UDP, TCP, HTTP, Serialization, .NET Remoting, WCF... how do I choose the "right" one (and are any important technologies missing from my list)?

My scenario is pretty simple: the client displays the current state of hundreds of objects on a map. There are two types of objects, each with many fields of state information. On connect, the server sends the state of all objects in a burst, after which incremental updates are sent. The client can also request historical data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF should be your default choice, unless you have some specific problem using WCF.

For instance, in some environments, WCF might conceivably might not be fast enough (doubtful). Only in that case would I chose anything else.

Remoting has been deprecated in favor of WCF. Serialization will be done for you by WCF, which can communicate either over HTTP or over raw TCP/IP. It will require little, if any, change in your service to change from one protocol to another.

Answer (score 0):

There are *lots* of ways to do this: you're actually designing your own application protocol, so the choice is totally yours; there is no "standard" way to have a client and a server communicate.

Do you want to have full low-level control on what the client and the server exchange? Then go with raw TCP (UDP is of no use here, as it is connectionless and it doesn't guarantee delivery); but you'll have to encode and transmit object data on your own, or serialize them and transmit them over a raw TCP stream.

WCF makes things a lot easier, encapsulating all of this for you; if both the client and the server are .NET applications running on recent frameworks, this should be your first choice.

Comment: I believe that I would choose WCF even for many UDP or "raw TCP" applications. You would need to create custom transports and message encoders, but once that's done, WCF will abstract the communication away from the service so that the rest of the service won't care what transport is being used.